# Custom Layer Not Training but not bugging

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a specific custom layer.  However, when I run it everything works out, no bugs, but after compiling and fitting I get no "training".  Ie, I get the same outputs as I fed in inputs...

```
  class Reconfiguration_unit(K.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Reconfiguration_unit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.weight = self.add_weight(shape=[input_shape[1],input_shape[1]], 
                                initializer='zeros',
                                trainable=True)
    self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=[input_shape[1],input_shape[1]], 
                                initializer='zeros',
                                trainable=True)
    self.location = self.add_weight(shape=input_shape[1:],
                                initializer='zeros',
                                trainable=True)
    self.scale = self.add_weight(shape=input_shape[1:],
                                initializer='zeros',
                                trainable=True)



def call(self, x):
    # 1. Shift and scale data
    x_shift = x - self.location

    # 2. Rescale componentwise
    x_mod = tf.math.multiply(x_shift,self.scale)

    # 3. Apply bumpy function Component-wise
    x_in_abs = tf.math.abs(x_mod)
    Logic_x_leq1 = tf.math.sign(tf.keras.activations.relu(1-x_in_abs)) # Takes value 1 iff |x|<=1 else 0: since probability of |x|=1 is 0 we should be ok
    x_thresheld = Logic_x_leq1*tf.math.exp(-1/(1-tf.math.pow(x_in_abs,-1))) # Computes bump function at thresholds with previous logic

    # 4+5. Apply Shift (In Tangent Space) and diagonalize
    x_out = tf.linalg.diag(x_thresheld) + self.bias 

    # 6. Multiply by weight matrix (in Tangent Space)
    x_out = tf.matmul(x_out,self.weight) 

    # 7. Apply Matrix Exponential
    x_out = tf.linalg.expm(x_out)

    # 8. Muliply by output of (1)
    x_out = tf.linalg.matvec(x_out,x_shift)

    # 9. Recenter Transformed Data
    x_out = x_out + self.location

    # Return Ouput
    return x_out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never (I mean, *never*...) initialize your weights as zeros! This is something you can do with biases, but never with weights.

Have a look at the available [initializers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers) - I would strongly suggest `GlorotUniform` (it's no accident that it is the default initializer for [Keras core layers](https://keras.io/layers/core/)) or `GlorotNormal`.

On a side note, it is not clear what your `location` and `scale` parameters are doing - you might want to also initialize them with something different than zeros.